# Frameworks for semantic annotation for user defined domain model

Tags: annotations, information-extraction, semantic-analysis

I have some documents and an ontology for some concepts. Are there any frameworks that automatically extracts those concepts from the given documents and creates triples? The ontology must contain special properties?

I found UIMA, but as far as I understood with UIMA I can do only something like this:

- create some dictionaries which keep associations with the ontology
- use this dictionary with ConceptMapper
- write a CAS consumer that creates the triples and persists them -

I don't like this approach because I have to keep in sync the concepts from the ontology and the dictionary.

Can be UIMA used differently, or are there any advanced frameworks that can use directly my ontology with lets say some custom properties as input and based on it annotate the documents?

I want to use ontologies as domain model because I want to create further a knowledge base and ontologies seem more flexible than for example relational model.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After spending more time searching on Google I found [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) and more specifically  [OntoRoot Gazetter](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch13.html#sec%3agazetteers%3aontoRootGaz) and [Large KB Gazetteer](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch13.html#sec%3agazetteers%3alkb-gazetteer).

> OntoRoot Gazetteer is a type of a dynamically created gazetteer that is, in combination with few other generic GATE resources, capable of producing ontology-based annotations over the given content with regards to the given ontology. This gazetteer is a part of ‘Gazetteer_Ontology_Based’ plugin that has been developed as a part of the TAO project.

I didn't test them but these ones seem good solution candidates for my problem.